# MySQL C++ Connector crashes when opening session

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I am trying to install and use the c++ connector. I downloaded the DEBUG version of the connector (I also compile in DEBUG). Linked the mysqlcppconn8.lib to my project, added the libcrypto-1_1.dll, libssl-1_1.dll and mysqlcppconn8-2-vs14.dll to my project directory. It compiles, but crashes when opening a session. It looks like a bad library or compatibility issue.I also added the preprocessor flag STATIC_CONCPP.

I use VS 2019 on Windows 10

Here is the minimal code that crashes:

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
int main()
{
    mysqlx::Session m_DBSession("mysqlx://root@127.0.0.1");

}
```

in the function:

```
Session(SessionSettings settings)
try
: Session_detail(settings)
{}
CATCH_AND_WRAP
```

with multiple memory errors like:

> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: cdk::foundation::Error at memory location 0x004EE30C.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: cdk::foundation::Error at memory location 0x004EE894.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x7620E062 in MainServer.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: mysqlx::abi2::r0::Error at memory location 0x004EEAD8.

I Tried multiple configurations:

- Tried using VS 2017 mode.
- Tried static and dynamic version of the library.
- Tried using /md, /mdt, /mdd.
- Tried with different Windows SDK version
- Tried the RELEASE version of the library and compiling in RLEASE the program

All of the above gives more or less the same issue with bad memory

Comment: It's a null pointer. I suspect your code ignores an error condition however you have not shown a [mcve]

Comment: Remember it's not usually safe to use c++ based debug dlls compiled with msvc on a release application or release dlls on a debug one. Don't try to force your compiler to compile if it complains about this.

Comment: I know it is a null pointer (or bad pointer or memory issue). But it happens inside the MySQL connector by just using a simple Session creation.

Comment: When using the debug MySQL connector, my program is also in debug. Same when I tried using the release, my program was in release. So they both matches.

Comment: I think you're right, I think it's a version issue. Are you 100% certain the libraries (static and dynamic) match your C++ header files?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue.

The Database I was trying to connect was not accepting the X Protocol and it was throwing a catch. The memory crash lead me to the wrong path thinking it was a compatibility issue.